# Access EXIF data in a NEF (Nikon) file

Tags: vb.net, exif

How can I access the EXIF data stored in a Nikon NEF file?  I can't seem to find a lib that will allow me to extract some basic information from the metadata.  (Preferably without having to install the Nikon codec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call out to a separate app like [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) or [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and then parse the output within your VB code.

Comment: Thanks - I've ended up doing something similar to this using IrfanView, mainly just because that's what I have already, and it can export all EXIF data to a text-file, including the maker-notes.

Comment: Oh, I did find out though that the NEF format is essentially TIFF though, so I should be able to use any lib that read TIFFs.